# Windows Phone 7.5 delay animation before "AutoReverse" is activated

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

Is there a way I can pause an animation before "AutoReverse" is activated?
I've got this storyboard:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="showMoreBox" AutoReverse="False" RepeatBehavior="1x" Completed="showMoreBox_Completed" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:0.7"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="showMore"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                                                    From="280" To="0">
                                                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                                    <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                                                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                            </DoubleAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
```

If I can't, how can I implement a slide in panel that will be delayed for a few seconds before sliding back in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an animation to your storyboard that does nothing for the desired amount of time:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="showMoreBox" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="1x" Completed="showMoreBox_Completed" FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="showMore">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.7" Value="0">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```